# WithTrashed() function deleting all trash instead of single ID

Tags: php, laravel

I have code that is using the withTrashed() and restore() methods.  Its working but it is restoring everything, not just the ID I want restored.  Not sure how to fix that.

Restore function

```
public function Restore($id){

    $delete = Category::find($id)->withTrashed()->restore();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Category has been restored successfully!');
}
```

Link and route for restore

```
<a href="{{ url('category/restore/'.$category->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Restore</a>
Route::get('/category/restore/{id}', [CategoryController::class, 'Restore']);
```

Model

```
   public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','user_id');
    }
```

Comment: You have the code in the wrong order... `Category::find($id)->withTrashed()->restore()` should be `Category::withTrashed()->find($id)->restore()`.

Comment: It doesn't restore anything like that

Comment: This  works for me `Category::onlyTrashed()->findOrFail($id)->restore();`

Comment: It wont restore if `$id` doesn't exist, probably `find($id)` returns null, you can use `findOrFail($id)`, it will raise a 404 error if $id doesn't exist on table

Comment: Either way, your code needs to be in the correct order. For example, if you did `Model::find($id)`, it'll return an instance of `Model`. If you then call a query function (like `withTrashed()`), **it'll start a new query without the `... WHERE id = ?` clause**. If you then chain a closure (like `restore()`), the query being run is `UPDATE model SET deleted_at = NULL`. Order of operations is important due to how models work. If you want an example, run `Category::find($id)->query()->delete()` and watch all of your records get deleted instead of just the one (Don't actually run that)

Comment: si I looked at   <a href="{{ url('category/restore/'.$category->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Restore</a> and it is passing the same ID for all entries.  Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. I was passing the wrong variable

 <a href="{{route('restore.category',$category->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Restore</a>

should be

 <a href="{{route('restore.category',$trash->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Restore</a>